# Recursively Check MKV with ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg

The basic of what I'm trying to do is to run through my old encodes recursively and output the results of ffprobe to a file so I can review it.

This is what I am trying and it is not working...

```
for /d /r "D:\Video\TEST" %%a in *.mkv do if exist "%%a" echo ffprobe.exe -i "%%a" -hide_banner >> results.txt
```

Also, Ideally I would like to exclude any "trailer.mkv" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/D` is for processing directories, not contents of directories.

```
for /r D:\Video\TEST %%a in (*.mkv) do (
  if "%%~nxa" neq "trailer.mkv" ffprobe.exe -i "%%a" -hide_banner 2>> results.txt )
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!  Now I get to figure out how to parse all of it so I can remove the extra audio and subtitles! :D